# PE: Adding code at the end of .txt section

Tags: c++, c, windows, exe, portable-executable

As I understand in `PE` file Virtual Size shows how much space it allocates for section during loading and Raw Size shows how big the section is on disk.

I came across to this executable which did the following:

It subtracted the virtual size (`offset 0x8`) from the raw data size (`offset 0x10`) and made sure there was some space(for example 100 bytes). At offset `0x14` from the text section header it found the offset in the file for the section itself. It added to this the virtual size, finding right where the section ends in the file. it copied some shellcode(which at the end eventually jumped to the original entry point of an executable to make sure original executable ran) to the end of the text section of the binary.

Now I'm little confused here, if the Virtual Size shows the exact space which will be allocated for executable, would not adding code at the end of `.txt` section overwrite some other data of executable and make it crash? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question and illustrates a very important point (or you might say quirk) about how the Windows loader calculates memory sizes.

The PE/COFF spec does indeed describe VirtualSize as "The total size of the section when loaded into memory".  This is technically true if you consider total to be the total amount of REAL data that comprises the section, but it is not the total amount of memory Windows allocates for the section.  You'll find VirtualSize is often LESS than the amount Windows allocates for the section in memory because VirtualSize must be rounded UP to the nearest memory alignment value (set in the PE image).

In other words, VirtualSize represents the unrounded size of the section while SizeOfRawData is the size of the data in the image file, but rounded up to the nearest file alignment padding value.  This is the reason VirtualSize is the better representation of the true "raw" size of the data, in memory or on disk.  The PE/COFF spec does not make this distinction.  Why one is rounded in the image file and not the other probably has its ancient roots in backwards compatibility.

This is precisely why your shellcode uses VirtualSize to find the "real" end of data even as it resides in the image file.  Not surprisingly, you can calculate SizeOfRawData by rounding VirtualSize up to the file alignment's value, at least in well formed PE files.

The shellcode simply used VirtualSize to find the end of the REAL code.  Between there and SizeOfRawData bytes, are just unused padding zeroes, making it a prime spot to add new code without affecting the size of the file or breaking addressing offsets within the PE file.

In summary, the Windows loader essentially takes the VirtualSize value and rounds it up to the memory alignment value to get the real size of the memory allocation (and even this may be rounded up to the nearest 4k-minimum memory page).  Then up to SizeOfRawData bytes are copied from the file to the beginning of the memory section.  If it is less than the size of the section in memory, the remainder is zero filled.

Comment: `VirtualSize represents the unrounded size of the section` this absolute wrong. `VirtualSize` - this how many memory reserved for section. `SizeOfRawData` - this is how many bytes have section on disk. for example section (`.bss`) have uninitialized data - in this case `SizeOfRawData` will be 0 - so `VirtualSize` > `SizeOfRawData`. from another size, because `SizeOfRawData` rounded to FileAligment (usual 512 bytes) can be and `VirtualSize < SizeOfRawData`.

Comment: The question wasn't about uninitialized data sections where SizeOfRawData=0; even in that case VirtualSize is still going to be the unrounded size of the section "in memory", there is just nothing to copy from disk. In almost any other case, the statement I made is a true implementation detail.  I agree its confusing and appears contrary to the spec, but this statement reflects how the MS Linker (and linkers that copied their behavior) are implemented. This also includes GNU and Borland Linkers.  Also note that a linker could round VirtualSize and still have a working executable.

Comment: As a side note on legacy behavior, Borland TLINK 4.x (from the early 90s) had VirtualSize and SizeOfRawData interchanged

Answer (score 1):

Uhmmm, this hack code seems crafted to hide malicious code between sections.

Going to your question, you are correct VirtualSize is the space really allocated in memory and RawSize is the the space used on disk to hold the section data.
What you missed is (from MS PECOFF spec):

> `VirtualSize`:    The total size of the section when loaded into memory. If this value is greater than `SizeOfRawData`, the section is zero-padded. This field is valid only for executable images and should be set to zero for object files.

This means that **if a the result of `SizeOfRawData`-`VirtualSize` is positive we have some space available on disk actually filled with 0's**.

If that space is enough to hold the malicious code then adding the start of text section on disk with the `VirtualSize` you can get the start of 0's padded area that can be used to copy the code.

The rest is story...

Comment: thank you for reply :) but even if code is added, only the `VirtualSize` of `.txt` section would be loaded when executing right?

Comment: Difficult to say if any control is made on the size. Considering that the section itself will be extended to a multiple of architecture page (PECOFF spec), some OS versions loaders could simply copy the whole block. **But anyway after so heavy modifications to change also the `VirtualSize` value is not a big deal...**

Comment: So your saying that `VirtualSize` isn't a big deal and loader will copy the whole block, meaning it will extend actual `.txt` section to a architecture page. Does this mean that `.txt` sections size which will be loaded will always be `RawDataSize`? Sorry if I misunderstood soemthing.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that after copying the data in the file, modifying also the `virtualSize` field at offset 0x8 adding the size of copied data cold be done to be sure the it will be loaded. **But at this point I really think we have talked too much of something that is not standard coding, and shouldn't be discussed because useful for bad practices.**